# TinyMCE 5 extended_valid_elements

Tags: image, tinymce

In input HTML I have the element:

```
 <img id="p_W_1" name="{1234}" class="po" src="../tinymce/plugins/myplugin/img/icon.png" data-mce-src="../tinymce/plugins/myplugin/img/icon.png" style="" data-mce-selected="1">
```

in editor init function

```
 extended_valid_elements:'img[id|src|class|data-mce-src|data-mce-selected|role|name]',
```

in otuput HTML no tags id, name

```
<img src="../tinymce/plugins/myplugin/img/icon.png" class="po" />
```

When I changed into

```
 extended_valid_elements:'img[id|src|class|data-mce-src|data-mce-selected|role]',
```

on result still no name

```
<img id="p_W_1" src="../tinymce/plugins/myplugin/img/icon.png" class="po" />
```

Comment: And next similar problem with:

<img style="width:100%;"

style tag has also removed.

Answer (score 0):

`extended_valid_elements` only allows valid HTML5 attributes, and `name` is not allowed on `<img>` tags, so `name` is removed.

Attributes like `data-mce-src` are internal to tinymce and shouldn't be used, so they are also stripped out.

Please see this example and choose View > Source Code on the editor:
https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/YShaab/5

However, if you add `name` to `extended_valid_elements`, you can see that `id` gets removed too:
https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/YShaab/7

This seems like a bug and I'll report it to the Tiny devs.